# Custom repository browser for a aloha editor image repository

Tags: aloha-editor

I'm trying to implement a repository browser for images to be inserted into an editable of the aloha-editor. The [browser plugin documentation](http://aloha-editor.org/guides/plugin_browser.html) does currently not specify how to customize columns and rows of a repository browser.

Anyone knows how to customize the rows of the browser plugin so i can display multiple thumbnails in each row of the repository browser - similar to the thumbnail view of the windows file browser?

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a hint. Try implementing the following two methods in the implementation of your browser:

```
    renderRowCols: function (item) {
        var row  = {},
            host = this.host,
            url = '',
            objTypeId;

        if (idMatch) {
            objTypeId = idMatch[1];
        }

        jQuery.each(this.columns, function (colName, v) {
            switch (colName) {
            case 'icon':
                row.icon = '<img src="/test.jpg"/>';
                break;
            case 'name':
                row.name = 'test';
                break;  
            default:
                row[colName] = '--';
            }
        });

        return row;
    },

    rowClicked: function(event) {
        var target = jQuery(event.target);


            this._super(event);

    }
```

This should point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks, but this would still require to have a single image per row if i understand correctly. what i'm actually trying to customize is to display multiple thumbs per row, kinda the "thumbnail" view in a windows file-explorer looks like.

Comment: so do you also want to have several items per row... like in the windows explorer?

Comment: I guess this would be a fair share of work since the browser is currently relying on tables where tr is always one item :/ you would have to extend the browser implementation and change that.